# Высота прыжка не всегда одинаковая

Tags: c#, unity3d

Реализовал прыжок с помощью `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Spase)`. Все работало нормально. После этого я добавил UI-кнопку прыжка и прикрепил на нее ту же самую функцию прыжка, что использовал до этого. В итоге прыжок с помощью кнопки в 2-3 раза ниже, чем с помощью нажатия на пробел.

Ситуация усугубилась, когда я попробовал поменять `GetKeyDown` на `GetKeyUp`. Теперь персонаж периодически прыгал высоко, а в остальное время низко, как при нажатии кнопки.
Вот код, отвечающий за управление персонажем:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HeroController : MonoBehaviour
{
//Oсновные параметры
[SerializeField] private float jumpForce;
[SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float maxSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed;
[SerializeField] private bool isGrounded;
[SerializeField] private float explosionForce;
private float maxExplosionForce;
private float maxExplosionJumpHeight = 6f;




//Ссылки на компоненты
private MobileController mController;
private Animator ch_animator;
private Rigidbody rb;
private Explosion explosion;

// Параметры геймплея
private Vector3 moveVector// направление  передвижения
{
    get
    {
        var horizontal = mController.Horizontal();
        var vertical = mController.Vertical();

        return new Vector3(horizontal, 0.0f, vertical);
    }
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start()
{
    explosion = GetComponent<Explosion>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    /*ch_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();*/
    mController = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Joystick")[0].GetComponent<MobileController>();

    maxExplosionForce = explosion.explosionForce;
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    GetJumpHeight();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Jump();
    }
    Move();
}

private void Move()
{
    //перемещение персонажа
    
    if (moveVector.magnitude > 0.1f)
    {
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveVector);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (rb.velocity.magnitude < maxSpeed)
    {
        rb.AddForce(moveVector * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);//метод передвижения 
    }
}
public void Jump()
{
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}

public void BUTTON_Jump() 
{
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
private void GetJumpHeight()
{
    if (!isGrounded && Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) <= 0.2f)
    {
        explosionForce = maxExplosionForce / maxExplosionJumpHeight * transform.position.y;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    IsGroundedUpate(collision, true);
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        explosion.Explode(explosionForce);
        explosionForce = 0f;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    IsGroundedUpate(collision, false);
}

private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    IsGroundedUpate(collision, true);
}

private void IsGroundedUpate(Collision collision, bool value)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == ("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = value;
    }
}
}
```

Так выглядит кнопка прыжка
[image]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы персонаж всегда прыгал на одну высоту и при нажатии пробела, и при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: Частота вызова FixedUpdate выше, чем частота вызова внутреннего обработчика нажатий кнопок мыши. Поэтому, при нажатии на кнопку, Jump вызовется один раз в кадр, а при нажатии пробела - несколько. Попробуй делать прыжок в Update, или, если надо работать с физикой строго в FixedUpdate, то делай так: в Update по нажатию пробела просто выставляй флаг doJump, а в FixedUpdate делай прыжок и флаг этот сбрасывай.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.05)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
```

попробуй этот код JumpForce, rb - это переменные, которые ты должен сам создать